# thymeleaf - why can't I pass a date value to controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

On my HTML5 page I have this code excerpt.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#timepicker4').timepicker({
                format: 'HH:mm'
            });
    </script>
// start of page
    <div class="header">    
        <label th:for="timepicker4" th:value="${hourIntervalStart}">Hour Interval Start: </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">                                                   
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
        <input name="hourIntervalStart" th:field="*{hourIntervalStart}" id="timepicker4" class="form-control tp_interval1"></input> 
    </div>
</div>
// rest of page
</body>
```

The problem is that, though the javascript is correctly displaying the time, the controller prints out (for testing purposes) a `null` value to the `hourIntervalStart` attribute.

The appropriate javascript library is correctly loaded and accessible from the browser.

How to correctly pass the the selected value to the controller?

Comment: Please add also your controller code.

Comment: I got it working, it was a problem casting from Date and String... Silly me!